# Double slash vs triple slash comments

Tags: c++, comments, codeblocks

I can't seem to find anything about this online.

```
//This is a comment
///This is a darker comment
```

In CodeBlocks, if I do a comment the first way it's almost impossible to see (light theme, not dark). If I do it the second way, it darkens the comment up considerably and I can see it better.

`C::B` obviously treats the two differently. Is there a real difference in these?

Comment: That's completely dependent on your text editor / IDE. There's nothing special of a `///` comment over a `//` comment regarding the c++ standard.

Comment: Consider to use the [visual-c++] tag if that is what you use.

Comment: The different/extended comments have meaning to code documentation packages, e.g. see [Doxygen - Documenting the code](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html)

Comment: In C++ `//` starts a comment that ends at the end of the line. `///` is a comment whose first character is `/`.

Answer (score 11):

This is Doxygen/JavaDoc syntax.

`///` indicates a short description that will be added to the Doxygen documentation. `//` will not add anything to Doxygen documentation.

Same for `/** */` which creates a long description vs `/* */` which doesn't create anything.

Your IDE (which you didn't specify) may render the different cases differently, or not.

Comment: I think C::B means the Code::Blocks IDE.

Comment: @jakub_d See [Doxygen - Documenting the code](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Syntax_highlighting_custom_colour_themes <- by their terminology one is a line comment and the other is a documentation comment line.

The compiler will ignore both.